# How to return a pointer to template struct?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, struct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* link;
    };
    struct Node* getNode();
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
private:
    Node* head;
};

template<class T>
struct Node* LinkedList<T>::getNode() // Error
{
    return head;
}

template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
}
```

As you can see I want to create a LinkedList class which can take any data type. I have problems with returning pointer to template struct.

Error message is `declaration is incompatible with...` (function declared up)

Comment: You would encounter the same problem if it weren't a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
template<class T>
struct Node* LinkedList<T>::getNode() // Error
{
    return head;
}
```

`Node` is scoped to `LinkedList<T>`.  Because you are not inside the function parameter list or the function body, the unqualified `Node`, is not available for you to use.  You have to scope the name using `LinkedList<T>::Node` to tell the compiler that you are using `LinkedList<T>`'s `Node`.  You also need to use the keyword `typename` when you do so since `Node` is a dependent name.  That means you need:

```
template<class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Node* LinkedList<T>::getNode()
{
    return head;
}
```

Or you could use a trailing return type and use

```
template<class T>
auto LinkedList<T>::getNode() -> Node*
{
    return head;
}
```

to save on typing all that out.

---

Also note that you do not need to use `struct` when you use the name of a `struct`.  That is/was required in C but it is not required in C++.

Comment: Or, it could be a trailing return type: `LinkedList<T>::getNode() -> Node*`

Comment: @JDoe Do you still get it if you change `struct Node* getNode();` to `Node* getNode();`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Right you are.  I forgot it was dependent on `T`.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody ^^

Comment: @eerorika Good idea.  I've added that to the answer.